# Wordpress: Filter/Sort posts within a page?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, filter, categories, posts

If I have a parent category, say, "Travel" with subcategories "belgium", "netherlands", "japan", etc., how can I create a page with all of the posts from the categories above? 
Then, I need users to be able to filter which posts they see, depending on which subcategory they choose.

If they want to see "travel" posts from the subcategory "japan", I need it to hide the other posts from "netherlands" and "belgium".

All this is done preferably without needing to refresh.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom query:

```
<?php
  $args = array( 
    category="xxx",
    // you set the parameters as you need.
  );
  $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );  
?>
```

Hope it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all of the posts in a single category, just link to the category's page. If you're using permalinks, the url should be of the form:

```
http://yourdomain.com/category/category_name
```

If you want to customize the appearance of that page, modify your theme's category.php template. If you want a different appearance for different categories you can create separate category-[slug].php templates.

As for doing the dynamic filtering of sub-categories without need of a refresh, my recommendation would be to add a `category-[slug]` class to each post's div on that category page, and then use jQuery to dynamically show/hide posts based on those classes.

Answer (score -1):

A detailed article is given [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-post-filters/) & it works I have tested it too.